# PyTorch: Dataloader for time series task

Tags: python, pandas, pytorch, torch

I have a Pandas dataframe with `n` rows and `k` columns loaded into memory. I would like to get batches for a forecasting task where the first training example of a batch should have shape `(q, k)` with `q` referring to the number of rows from the original dataframe (e.g. 0:128). The next example should be `(128:256, k)` and so on. So, ultimately, one batch should have the shape `(32, q, k)` with 32 corresponding to the batch size.

Since `TensorDataset` from `data_utils` does not work here, I am wondering what the best way would be. I tried to use `np.array_split()` to get as first dimension the number of possible splits of *q* values in order to write a custom DataLoader but then reshaping is not guaranteed to work since not all arrays have the same shape.

Here is a minimal example to make it more clear. In this case, batch size is 3 and *q* is 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(0,30).reshape(10,3),columns=['A','B','C'])
```

The dataset:

```
    A   B   C
0   0   1   2
1   3   4   5
2   6   7   8
3   9   10  11
4   12  13  14
5   15  16  17
6   18  19  20
7   21  22  23
8   24  25  26
9   27  28  29
```

The first batch in this case should have the shape (3,2,3) and look like:

```
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.]],

       [[ 3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

       [[ 6.,  7.,  8.],
        [ 9., 10., 11.]]])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your analog of the TensorDataset. To do this you need to inherit from the Dataset class.

```py
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_frame, q):
        self.data = data_frame.values
        self.q = q

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0] // self.q

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index * self.q: (index+1) * self.q]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only changed the code inside `__len__` to be `int(np.ceil(self.data.shape[0]/self.q))`

Comment: Using an array slice in `__getitem__` will result in an `iter()` method yielding empty arrays after getting through the data.

Answer (score 15):

I ended up writing custom dataset as well, though it's a bit different from the answer above:

```
class TimeseriesDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):   
    def __init__(self, X, y, seq_len=1):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.seq_len = seq_len

    def __len__(self):
        return self.X.__len__() - (self.seq_len-1)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.X[index:index+self.seq_len], self.y[index+self.seq_len-1])
```

And the usage looks like that:

```
train_dataset = TimeseriesDataset(X_lstm, y_lstm, seq_len=4)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size = 3, shuffle = False)

for i, d in enumerate(train_loader):
    print(i, d[0].shape, d[1].shape)

>>>
# shape: tuple((batch_size, seq_len, n_features), (batch_size))
0 torch.Size([3, 4, 2]) torch.Size([3])
```

Comment: Shouldn't be ```self.X[index:index+self.seq_len], self.y[index+self.seq_len]``` ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the open source library pytorch_forecasting.

Link to the time series dataset can be found [here](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_forecasting.data.timeseries.TimeSeriesDataSet.html)

Excerpt on the use of this dataset:
The dataset automates common tasks such as

1. scaling and encoding of variables
2. normalizing the target variable
3. efficiently converting timeseries in pandas dataframes to torch
   tensors
4. holding information about static and time-varying variables known
   and unknown in the future
5. holding information about related categories (such as holidays)
6. downsampling for data augmentation
7. generating inference, validation and test datasets

Tutorial [here](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/building.html#passing-data)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30918268)

Comment: Good point. Post edited