# How to correctly define a Pytorch dataset and dataloader for data which is scattered accross disk, AND in each file?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

1. I have data scattered across several files, say `f1`, `f2`, `f3` whose paths are `p1`, `p2`, `p3`.
2. Each file has say 1000 samples which can be loaded a `pandas` dataframe with `to_pd(path)`.
3. Files must be loaded in order due to an existing file-fetching system I already have in place.
4. Data within each file can be sampled randomly.

---

I've seen solutions for [loading from within a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57893415/pytorch-dataloader-for-time-series-task)
and for [reading a list of files](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-images-without-using-imagefolder/59999),
but not for doing both.

---

I can't think of a way to just define a custom pytorch Dataset because I don't have all paths in advance, but they come at runtime, only loading one after I'm finished with the last one.

I could make a dataset per file, but then I would have to create a dataloader that knows how to handle those multiple datasets.

---

What's the correct way of doing this in Pytorch?

I am also using Pytorch lightning if it helps.

Comment: "I don't have all paths in advance, but they come at runtime, only loading one after I'm finished with the last one. " - what do you mean? You will get to know those paths at some point, can't you detect their appearance using Python? Also you can load them as soon as they join the pool or whatever using a separate process or such. Also, in this light "you cannot make a dataset per file" as you don't know the paths to those files as said previously. Could you be more specific about your problem?